# Optimising SHA-1 for small input

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography, sha, 8051

I'm hoping to optimise an implementation of SHA-1 for an 8-bit MCU (8051-based). The input data is only 8-bytes, so I wonder if something could be done to improve this macro:

```
#define S(x,n) ((x << n) | ((x & 0xFFFFFFFF) >> (32 - n)))
```

The issue I have is that when macro `P` calls `S` with `S(b, 30)`, it takes around 60us to complete. Since there're 80 calls to `P`, it totals to around 4.8ms.

If I'm correct, `S(x,n)` expects `x` to be a `uint32`. Given the rather small input size, could the number of shifts be reduced by making `x` smaller, e.g., `uint8`?

If so, is this the only change needed? From:

```
#define S(x,n) ((x << n) | ((x & 0xFFFFFFFF) >> (32 - n)))
```

To:

```
#define S(x,n) ((x << n) | ((x & 0xFF) >> (8 - n)))
```

From:

```
void sha1_process( sha1_context *ctx, uint8 data[64] )
{
    uint32 temp, W[16], A, B, C, D, E;
    // ...
```

To:

```
void sha1_process( sha1_context *ctx, uint8 data[64] )
{
    uint8 temp, W[16], A, B, C, D, E;
    // ...
```

Here's the complete code:

```
#include <string.h>

#include "sha1.h"

#define GET_UINT32(n,b,i)                       \
{                                               \
    (n) = ( (uint32) (b)[(i)    ] << 24 )       \
        | ( (uint32) (b)[(i) + 1] << 16 )       \
        | ( (uint32) (b)[(i) + 2] <<  8 )       \
        | ( (uint32) (b)[(i) + 3]       );      \
}

#define PUT_UINT32(n,b,i)                       \
{                                               \
    (b)[(i)    ] = (uint8) ( (n) >> 24 );       \
    (b)[(i) + 1] = (uint8) ( (n) >> 16 );       \
    (b)[(i) + 2] = (uint8) ( (n) >>  8 );       \
    (b)[(i) + 3] = (uint8) ( (n)       );       \
}

void sha1_starts( sha1_context *ctx )
{
    ctx->total[0] = 0;
    ctx->total[1] = 0;

    ctx->state[0] = 0x67452301;
    ctx->state[1] = 0xEFCDAB89;
    ctx->state[2] = 0x98BADCFE;
    ctx->state[3] = 0x10325476;
    ctx->state[4] = 0xC3D2E1F0;
}

void sha1_process( sha1_context *ctx, uint8 data[64] )
{
    uint32 temp, W[16], A, B, C, D, E;

    GET_UINT32( W[0],  data,  0 );
    GET_UINT32( W[1],  data,  4 );
    GET_UINT32( W[2],  data,  8 );
    GET_UINT32( W[3],  data, 12 );
    GET_UINT32( W[4],  data, 16 );
    GET_UINT32( W[5],  data, 20 );
    GET_UINT32( W[6],  data, 24 );
    GET_UINT32( W[7],  data, 28 );
    GET_UINT32( W[8],  data, 32 );
    GET_UINT32( W[9],  data, 36 );
    GET_UINT32( W[10], data, 40 );
    GET_UINT32( W[11], data, 44 );
    GET_UINT32( W[12], data, 48 );
    GET_UINT32( W[13], data, 52 );
    GET_UINT32( W[14], data, 56 );
    GET_UINT32( W[15], data, 60 );

#define S(x,n) ((x << n) | ((x & 0xFFFFFFFF) >> (32 - n)))

#define R(t)                                            \
(                                                       \
    temp = W[(t -  3) & 0x0F] ^ W[(t - 8) & 0x0F] ^     \
           W[(t - 14) & 0x0F] ^ W[ t      & 0x0F],      \
    ( W[t & 0x0F] = S(temp,1) )                         \
)

#define P(a,b,c,d,e,x)                                  \
{                                                       \
    e += S(a,5) + F(b,c,d) + K + x; b = S(b,30);        \
}

    A = ctx->state[0];
    B = ctx->state[1];
    C = ctx->state[2];
    D = ctx->state[3];
    E = ctx->state[4];

#define F(x,y,z) (z ^ (x & (y ^ z)))
#define K 0x5A827999

    P( A, B, C, D, E, W[0]  );
    P( E, A, B, C, D, W[1]  );
    P( D, E, A, B, C, W[2]  );
    P( C, D, E, A, B, W[3]  );
    P( B, C, D, E, A, W[4]  );
    P( A, B, C, D, E, W[5]  );
    P( E, A, B, C, D, W[6]  );
    P( D, E, A, B, C, W[7]  );
    P( C, D, E, A, B, W[8]  );
    P( B, C, D, E, A, W[9]  );
    P( A, B, C, D, E, W[10] );
    P( E, A, B, C, D, W[11] );
    P( D, E, A, B, C, W[12] );
    P( C, D, E, A, B, W[13] );
    P( B, C, D, E, A, W[14] );
    P( A, B, C, D, E, W[15] );
    P( E, A, B, C, D, R(16) );
    P( D, E, A, B, C, R(17) );
    P( C, D, E, A, B, R(18) );
    P( B, C, D, E, A, R(19) );

#undef K
#undef F

#define F(x,y,z) (x ^ y ^ z)
#define K 0x6ED9EBA1

    P( A, B, C, D, E, R(20) );
    P( E, A, B, C, D, R(21) );
    P( D, E, A, B, C, R(22) );
    P( C, D, E, A, B, R(23) );
    P( B, C, D, E, A, R(24) );
    P( A, B, C, D, E, R(25) );
    P( E, A, B, C, D, R(26) );
    P( D, E, A, B, C, R(27) );
    P( C, D, E, A, B, R(28) );
    P( B, C, D, E, A, R(29) );
    P( A, B, C, D, E, R(30) );
    P( E, A, B, C, D, R(31) );
    P( D, E, A, B, C, R(32) );
    P( C, D, E, A, B, R(33) );
    P( B, C, D, E, A, R(34) );
    P( A, B, C, D, E, R(35) );
    P( E, A, B, C, D, R(36) );
    P( D, E, A, B, C, R(37) );
    P( C, D, E, A, B, R(38) );
    P( B, C, D, E, A, R(39) );

#undef K
#undef F

#define F(x,y,z) ((x & y) | (z & (x | y)))
#define K 0x8F1BBCDC

    P( A, B, C, D, E, R(40) );
    P( E, A, B, C, D, R(41) );
    P( D, E, A, B, C, R(42) );
    P( C, D, E, A, B, R(43) );
    P( B, C, D, E, A, R(44) );
    P( A, B, C, D, E, R(45) );
    P( E, A, B, C, D, R(46) );
    P( D, E, A, B, C, R(47) );
    P( C, D, E, A, B, R(48) );
    P( B, C, D, E, A, R(49) );
    P( A, B, C, D, E, R(50) );
    P( E, A, B, C, D, R(51) );
    P( D, E, A, B, C, R(52) );
    P( C, D, E, A, B, R(53) );
    P( B, C, D, E, A, R(54) );
    P( A, B, C, D, E, R(55) );
    P( E, A, B, C, D, R(56) );
    P( D, E, A, B, C, R(57) );
    P( C, D, E, A, B, R(58) );
    P( B, C, D, E, A, R(59) );

#undef K
#undef F

#define F(x,y,z) (x ^ y ^ z)
#define K 0xCA62C1D6

    P( A, B, C, D, E, R(60) );
    P( E, A, B, C, D, R(61) );
    P( D, E, A, B, C, R(62) );
    P( C, D, E, A, B, R(63) );
    P( B, C, D, E, A, R(64) );
    P( A, B, C, D, E, R(65) );
    P( E, A, B, C, D, R(66) );
    P( D, E, A, B, C, R(67) );
    P( C, D, E, A, B, R(68) );
    P( B, C, D, E, A, R(69) );
    P( A, B, C, D, E, R(70) );
    P( E, A, B, C, D, R(71) );
    P( D, E, A, B, C, R(72) );
    P( C, D, E, A, B, R(73) );
    P( B, C, D, E, A, R(74) );
    P( A, B, C, D, E, R(75) );
    P( E, A, B, C, D, R(76) );
    P( D, E, A, B, C, R(77) );
    P( C, D, E, A, B, R(78) );
    P( B, C, D, E, A, R(79) );

#undef K
#undef F

    ctx->state[0] += A;
    ctx->state[1] += B;
    ctx->state[2] += C;
    ctx->state[3] += D;
    ctx->state[4] += E;
}

void sha1_update( sha1_context *ctx, uint8 *input, uint32 length )
{
    uint32 left, fill;

    if( ! length ) return;

    left = ctx->total[0] & 0x3F;
    fill = 64 - left;

    ctx->total[0] += length;
    ctx->total[0] &= 0xFFFFFFFF;

    if( ctx->total[0] < length )
        ctx->total[1]++;

    if( left && length >= fill )
    {
        memcpy( (void *) (ctx->buffer + left),
                (void *) input, fill );
        sha1_process( ctx, ctx->buffer );
        length -= fill;
        input  += fill;
        left = 0;
    }

    while( length >= 64 )
    {
        sha1_process( ctx, input );
        length -= 64;
        input  += 64;
    }

    if( length )
    {
        memcpy( (void *) (ctx->buffer + left),
                (void *) input, length );
    }
}

static uint8 sha1_padding[64] =
{
 0x80, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
};

void sha1_finish( sha1_context *ctx, uint8 digest[20] )
{
    uint32 last, padn;
    uint32 high, low;
    uint8 msglen[8];

    high = ( ctx->total[0] >> 29 )
         | ( ctx->total[1] <<  3 );
    low  = ( ctx->total[0] <<  3 );

    PUT_UINT32( high, msglen, 0 );
    PUT_UINT32( low,  msglen, 4 );

    last = ctx->total[0] & 0x3F;
    padn = ( last < 56 ) ? ( 56 - last ) : ( 120 - last );

    sha1_update( ctx, sha1_padding, padn );
    sha1_update( ctx, msglen, 8 );

    PUT_UINT32( ctx->state[0], digest,  0 );
    PUT_UINT32( ctx->state[1], digest,  4 );
    PUT_UINT32( ctx->state[2], digest,  8 );
    PUT_UINT32( ctx->state[3], digest, 12 );
    PUT_UINT32( ctx->state[4], digest, 16 );
}

#ifdef TEST

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*
 * those are the standard FIPS-180-1 test vectors
 */

static char *msg[] = 
{
    "abc",
    "abcdbcdecdefdefgefghfghighijhijkijkljklmklmnlmnomnopnopq",
    NULL
};

static char *val[] =
{
    "a9993e364706816aba3e25717850c26c9cd0d89d",
    "84983e441c3bd26ebaae4aa1f95129e5e54670f1",
    "34aa973cd4c4daa4f61eeb2bdbad27316534016f"
};

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    FILE *f;
    int i, j;
    char output[41];
    sha1_context ctx;
    unsigned char buf[1000];
    unsigned char sha1sum[20];

    if( argc < 2 )
    {
        printf( "\n SHA-1 Validation Tests:\n\n" );

        for( i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
        {
            printf( " Test %d ", i + 1 );

            sha1_starts( &ctx );

            if( i < 2 )
            {
                sha1_update( &ctx, (uint8 *) msg[i],
                             strlen( msg[i] ) );
            }
            else
            {
                memset( buf, 'a', 1000 );

                for( j = 0; j < 1000; j++ )
                {
                    sha1_update( &ctx, (uint8 *) buf, 1000 );
                }
            }

            sha1_finish( &ctx, sha1sum );

            for( j = 0; j < 20; j++ )
            {
                sprintf( output + j * 2, "%02x", sha1sum[j] );
            }

            if( memcmp( output, val[i], 40 ) )
            {
                printf( "failed!\n" );
                return( 1 );
            }

            printf( "passed.\n" );
        }

        printf( "\n" );
    }
    else
    {
        if( ! ( f = fopen( argv[1], "rb" ) ) )
        {
            perror( "fopen" );
            return( 1 );
        }

        sha1_starts( &ctx );

        while( ( i = fread( buf, 1, sizeof( buf ), f ) ) > 0 )
        {
            sha1_update( &ctx, buf, i );
        }

        sha1_finish( &ctx, sha1sum );

        for( j = 0; j < 20; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%02x", sha1sum[j] );
        }

        printf( "  %s\n", argv[1] );
    }

    return( 0 );
}

#endif
```

Here's an example of the generated code for `S(x,n)` when called by `P( E, A, B, C, D, W[1]  )`:

```
 0031D0  85 18 82        MOV   DPL,XSP(L)
 0031D3  85 19 83        MOV   DPH,XSP(H)
 0031D6  78 08           MOV   R0,#0x08
 0031D8  12 17 85        LCALL ?L_MOV_X
 0031DB  74 1E           MOV   A,#0x1E
 0031DD  78 08           MOV   R0,#0x08
 0031DF  12 16 80        LCALL ?L_SHL
 0031E2  85 18 82        MOV   DPL,XSP(L)
 0031E5  85 19 83        MOV   DPH,XSP(H)
 0031E8  78 10           MOV   R0,#0x10
 0031EA  12 17 85        LCALL ?L_MOV_X
 0031ED  74 02           MOV   A,#0x02
 0031EF  78 10           MOV   R0,#0x10
 0031F1  12 16 67        LCALL ?UL_SHR
 0031F4  78 08           MOV   R0,#0x08
 0031F6  79 10           MOV   R1,#0x10
 0031F8  12 17 39        LCALL ?L_IOR
 0031FB  85 18 82        MOV   DPL,XSP(L)
 0031FE  85 19 83        MOV   DPH,XSP(H)
 003201  78 08           MOV   R0,#0x08
 003203  12 17 94        LCALL ?L_MOV_TO_X
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes, for 8bit MCU, your proposal to use byte-wise processing will yield better performance. I get the idea that 32 bit processing (in current code) is used to capture the optimized performance of the algorithm for 32bit processor (where register size is 32 bit).

Comment: (x & 0xFFFFFFFF) Here, AND operation is unnecessary in your macro (since x is 32 bit only). Simply x can be directly used.

Comment: Right. Do you mean that if x was an uint8, the AND operation would be unnecessary? How come?

Comment: 32 bit case -> (x & 0xFFFFFFFF), where x is 32 bit data, 8 bit case -> (x & 0xFF) where x is 8 bit data, in all cases, AND is being done with all 1's, so result is the original number x itself, so AND operation is insignificant. Yes, other case, like, x is 32 bit and AND is to mask 8 bits / 16 bits out of this 32 bit data, then, it makes sense. For example, in the posted code, is there a chance that S(x,n) is called with x as 64bit data?

Comment: I'm not entirely certain what `x` in `S(x, n)` is supposed to represent, since `x` could be `A`, `B`, `C`, etc. depending on the index of `W`. If the input is guaranteed to be 8-bytes or less, could `A`, `B`, `C`, ... `W[]` be all 8-bits long?

Comment: I do not know SHA algorithm, so, will not be able to comment about this. My comment about AND operation is not very significant, hence, can be ignored, it was purely based on C coding aspect. Have a look at http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2012/hash-algorithm-for-8-bits-mcu May be helpful.

Comment: 1) What do you want to achieve by hashing? Which security properties do you need? Hashing an input that's short and has a fixed size seems pointless to me. 2) How long an output will you use? 3) Are you open to other hashes besides SHA-1?

Comment: @CodesInChaos I'm hoping to use it for HMAC. The messages are small - 8 bytes only. The 8051-based core is very resource starved, so I think methods harder than SHA-1 may be too hard for it.

Comment: you might want to look into [lightweight cryptography](https://www.google.com/search?q=lightweight+MAC+crypto).

Comment: Ugh. Your compiler is generating god-awful code for those 'S' rotations, iteratively shuffling through a combined 32-steps on 32-bit variables for each one via run-time helper functions. Make use of a rotation intrinsics and take the short-way around if your compile has them, or tinker with the optimizations settings and fiddle with the intermediate type sizes and multiple-of-eight shifts to manually hint at the optimization opportunities for each shift count case. If all else fails drop the assembly if the compiler still refuses to take the hint.

Answer (score 1):

> If I'm correct, `S(x,n)` expects `x` to be a `uint32`. Given the rather small input size, could the number of shifts be reduced by making `x` smaller, e.g., `uint8`?

No. The state of the SHA1 function consists of five 32-bit values which change every iteration, and those values are what `S(x,n)` is operating on. Changing those into 8-bit values would give you a completely different (and probably very broken!) hash function.

The MD5/SHA family of hash functions all rely heavily on 32-bit integer operations. Ease of implementation on 8-bit processors, like the 8051, was not a design goal for these functions, and implementations on these parts will not perform particularly well. Sorry. You'll need to either live with the slowness, use another microprocessor (or one with SHA1 hardware acceleration!), or use a different hash algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your actual requirement is finding a MAC/PRF that's cheap to compute on your hardware for 8 byte inputs.

Since your data has fixed length, you can use a secure block cipher (with 128 bit blocks) as [CBC-MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBC-MAC). Since your data is shorter than one block, CBC-MAC simplifies to encrypting the data with the raw block cipher/ECB mode.

If your 128 bit block cipher has a similar cost-per-byte as SHA-1, this will result in an 8x speedup compared with HMAC-SHA-1 (SHA-1 has 512 bit blocks and you need to hash two blocks for HMAC). If you choose a cipher that's particularly suited for your CPU, the speedup might be even larger.

Since AES is so popular, [finding](https://www.google.de/search?q=AES+8+bit+CPU) implementations optimized for 8 bit CPUs shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: I did look into CBC-MAC, but i couldn't find an implementation for 8-bit processors - which is why I moved onto looking into SHA-1. Do you know of an implementation of CBC-MAC for 8-bit?

Comment: @Kar If you have an AES implementation, implementing CBC-MAC on top of it is simple. Just a bit xor-ing blocks, invoking AES, and a constant-time comparison in the end.